# sizeof struct with pack(push,1)

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have struct in qt project:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct test1{
    uint8_t a1 : 3;
    uint8_t a2 : 1;
    uint8_t a3 : 3;
    uint8_t a4 : 1;
    uint8_t a5 :3;
    uint8_t a6 : 1;
    uint16_t a7 : 12;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Check it sizeof.

```
qDebug() << "sizeof(Mi28NE::test1)" << sizeof(Mi28NE::test1);
```

Result in MinGW compiler:

```
>> sizeof(Mi28NE::test1) 3
```

Result in MSVC compiler:

```
>> sizeof(Mi28NE::test1) 4
```

Why?

Comment: You must use 3 bytes to represent the struct, but more is allowed. The MSVC version adds 1 byte to make it fit on a 4 byte boundary, which is nicer for caching on the CPU.

Comment: Bitfields are a very strong compiler implementation detail, there is just more than one way to do it.  Looks like GCC is using the available 4 unused bits in the uint16_t, MSVC does not.  Consider declaring *all* fields as uint32_t to get the same size on both compilers.

Answer (score 2):

bitfield is implementation specific.

It appears that msvc uses

```
struct test1{
    uint8_t  // a1, a2, a3, a4
    uint8_t  // a5, a6
    uint16_t // a7
};
```

Probably because `a6` uses `uint8_t` whereas `a7` uses `uint16_t`.

gcc appears to  pack `a5` and `a6` into the `uint16_t` used by `a7`.

You might have more similar result with:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct test1{
    uint8_t a1 : 3;
    uint8_t a2 : 1;
    uint8_t a3 : 3;
    uint8_t a4 : 1;
    uint16_t a5 : 3;
    uint16_t a6 : 1;
    uint16_t a7 : 12;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Answer (score -2):

Sizeof of this struct return true answer:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct test1{
    uint8_t a1 : 3;
    uint8_t a2 : 1;
    uint8_t a3 : 3;
    uint8_t a4 : 1;
    uint16_t a5 : 3;
    uint16_t a6 : 1;
    uint16_t a7 : 12;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: There is no "true" answer. And how does this answer the question? Is this a comment?